# xpath of following sibling which is stored as header and value

Tags: html, web, web-scraping, xpath, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract the flavour name - Fizzy Drink which has a label Flavour.
so far i tried Xpath - //span[contains(@class, "a-size-base a-text-bold") and text()="Flavour"] which gives me the flavour, I want to extract the value - Fizzy Drink using next sibling. Please help

```
<tr class="a-spacing-small">
<td class="a-span3">
<span class="a-size-base a-text-bold">Flavour</span>
</td>
<td class="a-span9">
<span class="a-size-base">Fizzy Drink</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you can use //td[position() > 1]/span/text() xpath

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xpath, "next sibling" is represented by the [following-sibling axis](https://www.scientecheasy.com/2019/08/xpath-axes.html/). So in your case:

```
//td[span[.="Flavour"]]/following-sibling::td//span/text()
```

should do it.

Comment: @Kanchan Glad to hear! If we're done, don't forget to accept the answer please.

Comment: Accepted, Thank you Jack